# REST API OIM 12c

Tags: rest, oim

We recently migrated to OIM 12c and with this migration we got the REST Api and I want to use it to start automating some of our daily tasks but until now I was unable to figure out how its implemented and how I can access it and use it. Can anyone give me guidance and maybe some general examples on how connect to  OIM 12c through Rest?
Thanks!

Comment: I think, Oracle provides some documentation to cover basics and details for REST API at https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/identity-governance/12.2.1.3/oimss/toc.htm Have you tried anything from there? Or do you have more specific questions based on the documentation and your experience?